# Methods For Listing Countable Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, algorithms, cardinals

The most famous (non trivial) example of listing a countable set is the argument showing that the rational numbers are countable:
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
\frac11 & \frac12 & \frac13 & \cdots \\
\frac21 & \frac22 & \frac23 & \cdots \\
\vdots  & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots
\end{array}
$$
But there are other countable sets that are much harder to draw out in this way. Since we know that the union of countably many countable sets is itself countable, I wonder if there are any other ways to draw out an argument for their countability.

In particular, I am trying to list all polynomials with where each term has a coefficient of 1.

If I try a similar approach to the above I quickly run into problems. If each row indicates how many terms in the polynomial there are then:
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
x^0 & x^1 & x^2 & \cdots \\
x^0+x^1 & x^0+x^2 & x^0+x^3 \\
\end{array}
$$
we clearly have a problem since this cannot help with showing all combinations of binomials like $x^1+x^2$, listing them this way will always give $x^0$ as the first term.

So, all in all my question is:

## What are some other ways to list countable sets?

Comment: "other ways", it depends on the set.

Comment: @Holo are there any other common methods? Or do most sets require completely different and novel approaches?

Comment: Consider the set of infinite sequences $(a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots)$ where each $a_n$ is 0 or 1 and all $a_n$ are zero from a certain value of $n$. This set can be identified with the set of polynomials you described. I know this doesn't answer your main question, but have you tried this view?

Comment: @LoganToll the usual method is: you have a set you want to list $A$, you have another set you *already* listed $B$, and then you find bijective function from $B$ to $A$, let's call this function $g$. then you take your listing for $B$ and use $g$ on them to create list for $A$. But a lot of times the hard part is to find $g$, for this there is no general method

Comment: @LoganToll if this answer the question let me know and I will post it as an answer with an example, if not, please let explain to me what exactly you want

Comment: @Holo, yes I think it does answer my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is not necessarily an answer to your question (other methods for listing countable sets), but here is a way to label the set of polynomials you described. You might find this approach useful.

Consider the polynomial $$a_n x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1 x^1 + a_0 x^0$$ where all the $a_n$ are 0 or 1. Write down the binary number $a_{n}a_{n-1}\ldots a_1a_0$. If you convert it to a decimal number, you have a way to label all the polynomials you described.

Example: the polynomial $x^3+x^2+x^1+x^0$ is the 7th polynomial, because 1111 is 7 in binary.

**Edit:** Now that I think about it, using the binary representation of positive integers, might be a useful approach to make a listing of a countable set.

Answer (score 1):

What we usually do not find the exact formula for the listing but use a different set that you already listed to create the new list.

Let $A$ be a set you want to list(let's assume that you can list it). Let $B$ be a set you already listed, let $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be the listing for $B$ and $g$ be a bijective function from $B$ to $A$, then define the list for $B$ like the following: $b_n=g(a_n)$.

---

For example, let $A=\Bbb C$(all 3 tuples of natural numbers), and let $B=\Bbb N^2$, now define $g(z)=(\Re(z),\Im(z))$ and $a_n$ be the listing of cantor.

Then the listing of $\Bbb C$ will be $g(a_n)$.

I know that this is a simple example, this is the most I could think about in the moment without defining new listing.

---

Added:

Also, note that most of the times you *won't* find a list at all, you will know that $a_n$ exists by some different methods, and then you can use $a_n$ to show that there exists a listing for $A$ *without* finding him exactly, only finding it in terms of $a_n$